# vim clang_complete VIo4231.tmp missing

Tags: windows, vim, clang, clang-complete

I installed the clang_complete plugin for vim and whenever the code completion has to come, it gives me this error(when setting g:clang_complete_copen = 1, so i can see the error)

> Error detected while processing function ClangComplete..32_ClangCompleteBinary:
>   line 15
>   E484: Can't open file C:\Users\GEBRUI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\VIo811.tmp

and when i start looking for that file isn't there.